# Output voltage of capacitor discharged in other capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, discharge, transient, capacitor-charging

Considering this circuit. How can I compute the maximum voltage across the resistor ?

In this example, the capacitor on the left is initialy charged with 10 V. The second capacitor (on the right) is not charged.

The simulation says that after the initial surge of discharging the charged cap into the other one, the maximum voltage across the resistor is 310 mV and then slowly decrease to 0 V (discharging the right cap into the resistor).

How is the value of 310mV computed?

[image]

Comment: Which node are you referring to when you say it's settling at 310mV?

Comment: The final voltage is easy, it is zero, after infinite time. Your simulation is wrong, you did not simulate infinite time.

Comment: @vir I'm refering to voltage accross the resistor

Comment: @Uwe of course, but i'm refering to the voltage after the surge, after the right cap is charged and starts discharging into the ressitor

Comment: There isn't any instant in time where that question makes sense.  Since the right cap and the resistor are in parallel, you can't charge the capacitor without also having current flow through the resistor.  That's what you're seeing in your graph.  An initial spike at t=0 and continuous exponential behavior afterwards.

Comment: If you dont want the final voltage, you should edit the question.

Comment: @Uwe i just did

Comment: @vir The whole point is to try to understand what happens during the initial phase and why the Max voltage across the resistor is 310mV. let me rephrase my question then: How do you compute the Maximum voltage across the resistor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless error.s ...
Here is a Maple sheet for "finding" function (voltage), ideal diode assumed)
See numeric output. The plot is "first" 300us.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The charge will equalize in short time scale and then drain with a longer time scale.

Capacitance in Farads is a unit Coulombs/Volt

Adding an additional 30x capacitance will mean that the same charge is distributed "thinner" so to speak.

Without knowing your initial conditions the voltage at t=0 would be roughly 1/30x of your initial voltage, with an additional drop (preventing true equalization) from the diode.

So if the initial condition 33uF charged to 30V, the situation just after t=0 would be 1.033mF at 1V, discharging through 10K resistance, a time constant of roughly ten seconds.

In other words at time t=10s the voltage will be roughly 370mV.

The time constant will experience a dual exponential, with a slightly shorter time constant after the diode stops conducting, followed by a longer trickle of current as the isolated capacitance bleeds away through internal resistance and diode leakage.

Comment: the 33uF cap is charged with 10V,when the charge equalize, how do you then compute the max voltage ?

Comment: Q=CV, C1V1=C2V2 you know 3 of the four so solve for V2.

Comment: C1V1 = C2V2 if only the 2 cap are in paralell no ? in this case, wouldn't some of the charge go through R also ?

Comment: Are they not in parallel? Yes the system does discharge through R, with a time constant of 10s.

Comment: In other words, to first order V(t)=V1C1/C2 (1-exp(-t/10))

Comment: yes, true, my point is that i tought the value of R had an effect on the value of the voltage ?

Comment: Yes, it is a time dependent voltage at t>0 you should have all the information to construct the first order model. The diode adds a nonlinear term at the end.

Comment: i'm not sure how to integrate it into the formula, but thanks anyway

Comment: The formula to account for the decay is a negative exponential V2 exp(-t/10) as per my comment from about 1 hr ago.